# Repeater fields with any content?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I like to add a repeater field with laravel-backpack. I'm trying to use table field, It works, but for text only. It's normal ?

I would like to use it to be able to give a title, an image to uploader and a link, with the corresponding fields type.

I'd like to do something like this

```
[ // Repeater field
    'name' => 'skills',
    'label' => 'Skills',
    'type' => 'table',
    'entity_singular' => 'skills', 
    'columns' => [
        'Your title' => 'text',
        'Your link' => 'link',
        'Your image' => 'image'
    ],
    'max' => 10
    'min' => 1 
],
```

thank you very much for your help

Comment: it should work with any fields. If you need any custom field add it in resources/vendor/views/base/fields i think and make your own custom field. Let me know if it works. If it doesn't i'll help you out. Oh btw name the blade table.blade.php to make the type table

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your solution. I tried to do as you said, but I do not understand too well. It must be 4 hours that I try to apply your solution by leaving table and I can not. I start in PHP, I try to understand things but it's not easy. If you have the solution, it would be very nice and I'm sure it could help other people!

Thank you very much !

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more explicit and also I was slightly wrong. It was very late for me. here we go: in resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields there is a list of fields already provides by backpack. Besides that you can add any of your custom fields. Then you need to create it fitting your needs. I recommend doing it as general as possible so you can reuse it.

Comment: If it does not solve your question find me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139482/backpack-isses

Comment: did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Thank you for your help **@Indra** ! I put this aside for the moment, I would come back in a few weeks, when I would have advanced in my project of end of study. I first do the front-end, I tried a few tricks but I did not get there but I was not in my real project. I'll keep you informed !

thank you very much